# maximumBillingTier with Simba ODBC drivers

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the free Simba ODBC drivers from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/

I've encountered the error:

```
Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 4 or higher required.
```

There are docs for addressing this ( https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute ) when using the REST API.

Is it possible to request a maximumBillingTier over ODBC? I've tried adding:

```
#maximumBillingTier=4
```

... to the 1st line of the query, but this doesn't appear to be honored ( maybe it's overridden by the ODBC driver? ).

Answer (score 1):

The simba drivers don't expose this setting, so setting a project default is the best way to address this today.